# Lua get and execute function from C

Tags: c, api, function, lua

If I have some lua code like this:

```
doSomething(function()
                print("Hello!")
            end)
```

How can I make it that, using the C API, I create C Lua function for doSomething that can then save the function passed to it to be executed a later date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a normal entry on the stack.  Check it with `lua_isfunction()` then use `luaL_ref()` to generate a reference (so that the garbage collector doesn't steal it), and then maybe `lua_topointer()` to store a pointer to this object, depends what you want to do with it.

When you're finished it's just a `luaL_unref()`.

Comment: Oh overlooked the later execute bit, that's just `lua_call()` but make sure you read the details under http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_call